# Border Radius not showing right

Tags: border, css

I set a border-radius in my style sheet on all images in a certain div.
Works fine, except that in some browsers the radius isn't round at all?

I set it for IE, webkit, and moz. But in IE10 for example there's no radius at all except the bottom right corner.

Example1

Code:

```
div#dienstright img{

border-bottom-left-radius:25px;
border-bottom-right-radius:25px;
border-top-left-radius:25px;
border-top-right-radius:25px;

-moz-border-radius:25px 25px 25px 25px; 

-webkit-border-top-left-radius:25px; 
-webkit-border-top-right-radius:25px; 
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:25px; 
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:25px; 
}
```

Comment: Most decent browsers support the simple syntax http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius so `border-radius:25px;` should suffice. Only IE8 will downgrade (and Opera mini)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, its the padding on your `img` you have `10px` of padding on top/left if you remove that the border-radius will show up as expected.

The long & short-hand syntax for `border-radius` works just fine in IE9 + 10

Answer (score 0):

For IE use:

```
border-radius: 25px;
```

It should be enough to work just fine. And since you have same value for every corner there's no need to specify each corner separately.

if you need to specify separately use:

```
border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
```

The values are in order: top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left

Comment: I just specified them seperately in an attempt to troubleshoot.Its no fix when I just write    border-radius:25px;